# How to use apply or sapply or lapply with ffdf?

Tags: r, bigdata

Is there a way to use an apply type construct directly to the columns of a ffdf object?  I am trying to count the NAs in each column without having to turn it into a standard data frame. I can get the na count for the individual columns using:

```
sum(is.na(ffdf$columnname))
```

But is there a way to do this for all the columns in the dataframe at once, something like:

```
lapply(ffdf, function(x){sum(is.na(x))})
```

When I run this I get:

```
$virtual
[1] 0

$physical
[1] 0

$row.names
[1] 0
```

I have not been able to find a special version of lapply or sapply in the ff documentation.  Further is there a simple way to count the NAs over the entire ffdf in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ffdf is basically a list with elements "virtual", "physical", "row.names".
If you do an lapply over the physical element, you have what you want.

```
require(ffbase)
myffdf <- as.ffdf(iris)
lapply(physical(myffdf), FUN=function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

As is.na and sum is generic, this will basically use `is.na.ff` and `sum.ff` from package ffbase such that data is loaded into RAM chunkwise according to what your computer can handle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  My computer's hard disk isn't so grateful though!