# R{ff}- use apply in ffdf

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm interested on using apply on a ffdf. I think I can't use ffdfdply because I'm not interested on splitting columns, because I have to use all components of the row, formed by 4 components("identifier1" "identifier2" "value" and "condition"), to fill 2 matrix depending on a condition. 
As this prior thread proposes ([How to use apply or sapply or lapply with ffdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885561/how-to-use-apply-or-sapply-or-lapply-with-ffdf)) I've tried this:

```
apply(physical(myffdf),1,function(x){

  if( x["condition"]=="A"){
        matrix1[x["indentifier1"],x["identifier2"]] <<- x["value"]
  } ifelse( x["condition"]=="B") {
        matrix1[x["indentifier1"],x["identifier2"]] <<- x["value"]

  }
})
```

but I've read that physical() returns a list with atomic ff objects, so logically I can't use apply. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you want to apply a function over the rows. You can use chunk for that. Get you chunk in RAM and use apply and store it where you want (in RAM or in ff).

```
require(ff)
ffiris <- as.ffdf(iris)
for(i in chunk(ffiris)){
  x <- ffiris[i, ]
  apply(x, MARGIN=1, FUN=yourfunction)
}
```

Comment: Doing this: 'for(i in chunk(myffdf)){
      x <- myffdf[i, ]
      apply(x,1,FUN=function(x){
             if( x["condition"]=="A"){
        matrix1[x["indentifier1"],x["identifier2"]] <<- x["value"]
  } ifelse( x["condition"]=="B") {
        matrix1[x["indentifier1"],x["identifier2"]] <<- x["value"]                  
            }
      })
}' appears tha following error: Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, x["identifier1"], x["identifier2"], value = "SERINC1") : 
  subscript out of bounds. But I've checked that "SERINC1"(which is an identifier2) exists in both matrix1 and 2.

Comment: Looks like your FUN contains bugs. Fix it. Also I advise you not to use <<-. It is bad practice to use that inside a function unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I've checked the bugs and now it's running, thanks. BTW.Do you know any good tutorial for ff package or ffdf objects? I've been struggling with the CRAN pdf :S